# 500 error when authenticating ALB + AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, aws-application-load-balancer

I am trying to authenticate Lambda via Aws ALB + Cognito. When I launch the DNS server, it redirects me to login page, I'm able to signup and verify the user. Also, I could see the user added to users in userpool. After sign in, it gives 500 Internal Server Error.
The default action forward to function is getting executed in the background, I could see in the logs.

Not sure why it is not redirecting/executing lambda after authenticating the user. Could you please provide some insight, what would I be missing in this setup.

I have set up the Lambda, ALB and Cognito in terraform.

```
resource "aws_cognito_user_pool" "pool" {
  name                       = "alb-test-userpool"
  alias_attributes = ["email", "preferred_username"]
  verification_message_template {
  default_email_option = "CONFIRM_WITH_CODE"
  }
  email_verification_subject = "Device Verification Code"
  email_verification_message = "Please use the following code {####}"
  sms_verification_message   = "{####} Baz"
  auto_verified_attributes   = ["email"]

  password_policy {
      minimum_length    = 8
      require_lowercase = false
      require_numbers   = false
      require_symbols   = false
      require_uppercase = false
    }
  tags {
    "Name"   = "alb pool"
    }
 schema {
  name                = "email"
  attribute_data_type = "String"
  mutable             = false
  required            = true
}
}

resource "aws_cognito_user_pool_client" "client" {
  name = "alb-test-user-client"
  user_pool_id = "${aws_cognito_user_pool.pool.id}"
  generate_secret = true
  allowed_oauth_flows_user_pool_client = true
  supported_identity_providers = ["COGNITO"]
  callback_urls = ["https://internal-****-****.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com/oauth2/idpresponse"]
  allowed_oauth_flows  = ["code"]
  allowed_oauth_scopes = ["openid"]
  explicit_auth_flows = ["ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH"]
  allowed_oauth_flows_user_pool_client = true
}

resource "aws_cognito_user_pool_domain" "pool_domain" {
  domain          = "${var.domain}"
  user_pool_id    = "${aws_cognito_user_pool.pool.id}"
}
```

Comment: We have similar issue, Cognito SAML to Google IdP and getting 500 from ELB on the post back to idpresponse. The forward action is still executed, because I can see it in the app logs.

Comment: Fir posterity: our ALB was configured with incorrect "email" scope. Changing scope to "openid" on the ALB HTTPS listener rule, fixed our issue.

Answer (score 9):

The load balancer is unable to communicate with the IdP token endpoint or the IdP user info endpoint. Verify that the security groups for your load balancer and the network ACLs for your VPC allow outbound access to these endpoints. Verify that your VPC has internet access. If you have an internal-facing load balancer, use a NAT gateway to enable internet access.

[AWS docs about 500 issues](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-troubleshooting.html#http-500-issues)

Comment: In my case using CDK I had to add something like: `loadBalancer.connections.allowToAnyIpv4(ec2.Port.tcp(443), "Allow ALB to communicate with Cognito IdP endpoint")`

Comment: In my case Security Group Outbound has only HTTP, i added another route for HTTPS and it started working.